# Class 'highcharts\Highcharts' not found [yii2 manually install extension]

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

So I am new in Yii2. I'm trying to install the first extension on my app (I plan to host the webapp). I've tried working with composer but it doesn't work.

I place the extension folder here: `vendor/highcharts/src/`

This is what I write in **extension.php:**

```
'highcharts' => array(
'name' => 'highcharts',
'version' => '4',
'alias' => array(
      '@highcharts' => $vendorDir . 'highcharts',
    ),
),
```

In **autoload_psr4.php:**

```
'highcharts\\' => array($vendorDir . '/highcharts/src'),
```

Di **view.php:**

```
<?php
use highcharts\Highcharts;
echo Highcharts::widget([
   'options' => [
     'title' => ['text' => 'Fruit Consumption'],
   'xAxis' => [
      'categories' => ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
   ],
   'yAxis' => [
      'title' => ['text' => 'Fruit eaten']
   ],
   'series' => [
      ['name' => 'Jane', 'data' => [1, 0, 4]],
      ['name' => 'John', 'data' => [5, 7, 3]]
   ]
   ]
]) ;
```

This is what the error is **saying:**

> Class 'highcharts\Highcharts' not found

I've tried editing the `use`  part. But still no results. So what have I missed?

Comment: share extension link !!

Comment: have you created the widget? you need to create a widget first,here is a guide to creating widgets http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-widgets.html of which you will end up with a similar extention as this on https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad here is the link: https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts

Comment: @chapskev, isn't `echo  Highcharts::widget([ ...` creating the widget itself? Please help me understand more.

Comment: You can add highcharts.js files on your asset manager file or register the respective files on your view and then write your own js alternatively you can use this extension https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget and install via composer. https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget

Comment: I suggest you put this extension in composer and then use it otherwise you will face so many issues.

Answer (score 0):

in **extension.php**:

```
'miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget',
    'version' => '5.0.2.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@miloschuman/highcharts' => $vendorDir . '/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget/src',
    ),
  ),
```

and in **autoload_psr4.php**:

```
'miloschuman\\highcharts\\' => array($vendorDir . '/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget/src'),
```

---

But why you work without **composer**?

You can add

```
"miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "^5.0"
```

to composer.json

and run

```
composer update
```